# how to make a ball move in opposite direction when hitter to ball or paddle

Tags: cocos2d-x

I had set angle but it's not correct and I'm not getting exactly what I needed. The ball should bounce when hit to paddle or border and move in opposite direction. I'm writing the code in c++.

I had presently written this code when the ball and paddle intersects and I couldn't get how the code is working.

```
auto paddleY=paddleSpr->getPositionY();
auto intersectY=ballSpr->getPositionY();

auto paddleheight=65;
auto maxBounceAngle=45;
auto speed =1550;

auto relativeIntersectY=(paddleY+(paddleheight/2))-intersectY;


auto normalizedRelativeIntersectY=(relativeIntersectY/(paddleheight/2));

auto  bounceAngle=normalizedRelativeIntersectY*maxBounceAngle;

float vx = cos(bounceAngle * M_PI / 180) * speed;
float vy = sin(bounceAngle * M_PI / 180) * speed;

pbody11->setVelocity(Vect(vx,vy));
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I had added my code .plz help me.

Comment: I really don't like auto for int's, i can't help it.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion , setting speed to negative should fix the problem ( which negative is opposite with positive ) :

```
auto paddleheight=65;
auto maxBounceAngle=45;
auto speed=-1550;

auto relativeIntersectY=(paddleY+(paddleheight/2))-intersectY;


auto normalizedRelativeIntersectY=(relativeIntersectY/(paddleheight/2));

auto  bounceAngle=normalizedRelativeIntersectY*maxBounceAngle;

float vx = cos(bounceAngle * M_PI / 180) * speed;
float vy = sin(bounceAngle * M_PI / 180) * speed;

pbody11->setVelocity(Vect(vx,vy));
```

***UNTESTED*** , because it is not possible without full project file .